# How do i know timezones - PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

How can i know the current time at different places

example:-

Local time in America & london wud differ

1) So if a user from USA visit my website, I should be able to show him his local time
2) If a user from London visit my website, his/her local time should be populated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript you can find the user location from the browser.

You should keep a data base for finding the difference of GMT time and the countries.

Based on the location you got from javascript , generate date difference from db and show.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2023-Geocoding-A-User-s-Location-Using-Javascript-s-GeoLocation-API.htm

Based on IP also you can find location .

http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/06/29/determine-your-visitors-location-based-on-ip-address/

http://briancray.com/2009/05/29/find-web-visitors-location-javascript-google-api/

Comment: wow, thanq so much...second link helped me a lot, Search Country/City by IPaddress...my issue can be solved in few hrs...thanx a lot zod